# Python PyQt5 QTableWidget contextMenuEvent setStyleSheet submenu background colour

Tags: python-3.x, pyqt5, stylesheet, qtablewidget

I have a context menu in my PyQt5 QTableWidget.

```
def contextMenuEvent(self, event):
    """Open context menu for selected items."""

    selected_items = self.selectedItems()
    if selected_items:

        menu = QMenu(self)
        menu.setStyleSheet("""
            QMenu {border: 1px inset grey; background-color: #fff; color: #000; padding: 0;}
            QMenu:selected {background-color: #ddf; color: #000;}"""
        )
        # File submenu
        file_menu = QMenu("File")
        delete_action = file_menu.addAction("Delete")
        menu.addMenu(file_menu)

        # Format sub_menu
        format_menu = QMenu("Format")
        format_split_action = format_menu.addAction("Split address")
        format_title_case_action = format_menu.addAction("Title Case")
        menu.addMenu(format_menu)

        menu.addSeparator()

        # Quick links
        menu.addAction("Split address")
        menu.addAction("Title Case")

        action = menu.exec_(self.mapToGlobal(event.pos()))
        if action:
            if action == format_title_case_action:
                self.format_title_case()
            elif action == format_split_action:
                self.split_address()
            elif action == delete_action:
                self.remove_selected_rows()
```

The style sheet formats the menu almost how I want it, but it does not change the background colour of the submenus (File & Format), which still have a grey background:

[image]

I presume that I need to add another entry to the style sheet for the sub menu style. Does anyone know what I need to add?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Stylesheets are inherited only by children of the widget they are applied to.
If you add a menu to another one it won't make it a child of it, and that's because the same menu could be used in multiple situations (from [QMenu.addMenu(QMenu)](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qmenu.html#addMenu)):

> This menu does not take ownership of menu.

The solution is to set that main menu as parent of each children for which you want the stylesheets applied to:

```
    menu = QMenu(self)
    menu.setStyleSheet("""
        QMenu {border: 1px inset grey; background-color: #fff; color: #000; padding: 0;}
        QMenu:selected {background-color: #ddf; color: #000;}
    """)
    file_menu = QMenu("File", menu)
```

Alternatively, you can do the same with [`QMenu.addMenu()`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qmenu.html#addMenu-1):

```
    file_menu = menu.addMenu("File")
```

It's not your case, but it's worth noting that if you use that child menu somewhere else the main menu will still be its parent, and as such will have the same stylesheet.

Comment: Perfect, thank you :-) I just added ", menu" to each child menu. Eg.
file_menu = QMenu("File", menu)